# Is it possible that python takes very long to assign a name to a huge list (~10 gb)?

Tags: python, bash, list, nlp, corpus

I am working with a very long list of lists (I'm talking 10 gb if you put it in a file), a cleaned corpus. In my script, I assign it a name, and then use it in another function that has to do with word2vec/spacy and semantic similarity (calculate for each word in a list of words what is their semantic similarity, i.e. how similar are the contexts in which these words appear). I have many steps in my script and I ask it to print something after some of the steps, all to an output file. I am using bash to execute the script. It's been 3 hours, and nothing is in my output file, which I assume means that the list has not been assigned the name yet. However, when I run a .py script with only the list in it (also assigned to a name), it takes very short. Also, the model usually loads very quickly, so that shouldn't be the problem, either. So... am I doing something wrong here? This is how I made the list (that process worked, I already have the list!) and the actual list is just a huge list of lists:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import re
import nltk
import string
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
punct = string.punctuation + '«»' + '``'

def read_lines_from_big_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if len(line) > 1:
                parts = word_tokenize(line) 
                yield parts

contexts_big = []    

            
for split_line in tqdm(read_lines_from_big_file('.../corpus.txt')):
    if 'CURRENT' not in split_line:
        clean_2 = [re.sub('\x93|\x94|\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower()) for x in split_line if re.sub('\x93|\x94|\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower()) not in stopwords.words('italian') #don't include if the word is a stopword
        and re.sub('\x93|\x94\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower()) != " " #don't include extra empty spaces
        and re.sub('\x93|\x94\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower()) not in punct #double check that all punct is removed
        and len(re.sub('\x93|\x94\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower())) > 1
        and not re.match(r'http\S+|\d+|\n|www\S+', re.sub('\x93|\x94\x92|l\'|un\'','',x.strip(punct).lower()))] #to remove any remaining stopwords or just random letters
        contexts_big.append(clean_2)
    else:
        continue

contexts_big = [[...],[...],[...],...]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The assignment isn't the slow part. We can't tell what *is* the slow part, but it's definitely not the assignment.

Comment: Right, sorry, thank you. I can put more code, but isn't it weird that it doesn't print out that it loaded the model, especially since usually that's very fast?

Comment: You aren't literally saying you want to compare every word in a 10GB list of words against every other word, are you?  If the average word is 10 letters long, you're talking about a QUINTILLION comparisons.  It will never finish, and you do not have enough memory or disk space to store the results.

Comment: @TimRoberts no, no! I have a separate list of words (around 20) and I need to see what is the similarity between contexts in which they appear. So first I need to see what are in fact the words that are in the contexts, to filter them out. Then I compare pairwise similarities between contexts for each word. But the problem is that I know my script is not there yet, because I have a tqdm in my function and it would show me some progress, but it's not showing me anything... not even that the model has loaded

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to cast to a list in `for tup in list(itertools.combinations...`.  If you have a large set, remember that the `list` cast forces the ENTIRE set of combinations to be present in memory before the first statement of the loop runs.  Just leave the `list` off, and it will generate one at a time without consuming memory.

Comment: @TimRoberts ah, thank you!

Comment: Instead of `read = stimoli.read().split("\n")`, you can do `read = stimoli.readlines()`, but why do you remove all the blanks?

Comment: When you talk about an output file, does that mean you're doing something like `python yourprog.py > output.txt`? Because if you're directing output to a file instead of a terminal, output gets buffered in blocks instead of by line, so you're not going to see anything until a whole bunch of output has been written.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, but I have it after a block, so it should print something (I tried with a smaller sample and it worked...).

Comment: In the process of loading the list I see a big load of calculus through regular expressions. Some speed should be gained if you compile the expressions and use the resulting patterns. You are also repeating some calculus over and over, like every call to `x.strip(punct).lower()`. You should do that calculus once and reuse the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with huge files, you have to think about memory management.  Let's take apart this sequence:

```
with open("...stimoli.txt", 'r') as stimoli:
    read = stimoli.read().split("\n")
    stimoli = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in read]
```

First, we have `stimoli.read()`.  That's going to read the ENTIRE FILE into memory as a single string.  That statement cannot proceed until the entire file is in memory.  So, there's 10GB.

Next, we have `.split("\n")`.  That will start with that single 10GB string, will search for the newlines, and create a list with lines.  This list will be ANOTHER 10GB, that has to exist in memory at the same time as the first.  That's 20GB of memory altogether.  That's huge.

Now, we assign that 10GB list to `read`, so there's an outstanding reference.  Next, we do: `[x.replace(" ", "") for x in read]`  Because of the outer brackets, that has to create ANOTHER full list in memory.  That list will also be 10GB.

So, that simple set of lines has created 30GB of allocations, of which 20GB will stick around when the statement exits.

Compare to this:

```
with open("...stimoli.txt", 'r') as stimoli:
    stimol = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in stimoli]
```

That calls `file.readline` repeatedly, which never has to allocate more than a line at a time.  It will eventually create a 10GB list of strings, but we only had to allocate 10GB, not 30GB.

Comment: Thank you again, this is very useful, but it is not exactly the problem. Sorry, I should have explained myself better. The 'stimoli.txt' file is very small, just 20 words. It is the words I am going to calculate the semantic diversity for through the contexts_big list, which is the 10 gb list... So the problem is that I don't even arrive to the stimoli file... The contexts_big list seems to be the problem somehow, but I don't really understand how, since my script doesn't even arrive to inputting into any function, but merely assigning a name to it.

Comment: I guess I should have asked WHICH thing is big, and exactly WHICH print statement you're not seeing.

Comment: this list is huge: contexts_big = [[...],[...],[...]...] and this:
print('assigned name') does not print even after a few hours

Comment: How is `contexts_big` created?  Is it read from file?

Comment: It was created through another script, printed to a file. I added the contexts_big to assign a name to it, and then combined it with the command cat with the rest of my code, because importing the variable was making me run out of RAM.

Comment: In other words: you are showing us a lot of non-related code and hiding us the relevant code. If you don't see the "assigned name" output and the problem is in the lines before, then we need to see the lines before. In this case, seeing exactly how the `contexts_big` is created/loaded/managed is relevant.

Comment: @tryingtoprogram you may be stuck at the compilation of the code: a 10GB source file is no small matter...

Comment: So, you have a 10GB Python file?  I never would have guessed.  That's never going to work.  You need to have that in a format that can be read in as data: JSON, or CSV or some more compact form.

Comment: `contexts_big` was created through a line-by-line cleaning process in an earlier stage. I will try with using another format. But if Python can't even read the data, how can it transform it in another format?

Comment: @Poshi I've added the code before, but that is not so relevant anymore, because that ran already from another script, and I do have the list in my hands now.

Comment: Because reading a data file is a less computationally-intensive process that compiling a language statement.  It still might not fit into memory, but it has a better chance.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, I can see that you are repeating a set of heavy computations over and over, while you probably can do it once and reuse the result.
Whet about the following schema?

```
for split_line in tqdm(read_lines_from_big_file('.../corpus.txt')):
    if 'CURRENT' not in split_line:
        tmp = [
            re.sub('\x93|\x94|\x92|l\'|un\'', '', x.strip(punct).lower())
            for x
            in split_line
        ]
        clean_2 = [
            x
            for x
            in tmp
            if x not in stopwords.words('italian')
                and x != " "
                and x not in punct
                and len(x) > 1
                and not re.match(r'http\S+|\d+|\n|www\S+', x)
        ]
        contexts_big.append(clean_2)
    else:
        continue
```

You perform the stripping, lowercasing and regex substitution once. Then, you validate the results.
I'm not sure if I got the regex OK, as they were not identical, but so similar that I assumed it was a typo.
This can be further refined, but I suspect that this change will give a noticeable speedup.